# Apply function to each unique value of column seperately

Tags: python, for-loop, group-by, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe with more than 500 cities which look like this

| city | value | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| london | 23 | 2022-03-25 17:59:18 |
| dubai | 12 | 2022-03-25 17:59:36 |
| berlin | 5 | 2022-03-25 17:59:42 |
| london | 25 | 2022-03-25 18:01:18 |
| dubai | 12 | 2022-03-25 18:02:18 |
| berlin | 5 | 2022-03-25 18:03:18 |

I have a function called rolling_mean which creates a new column 'rolling_mean' which calculates the last hour rolling average.

```
def rolling_mean(df):
    df['rolling_mean'] = (df.set_axis(datetime)
                        .rolling('1h')['value']
                        .mean()
                        .set_axis(df.index)
                      )
```

However I would like to apply this function to each city separately so that when the new rolling_mean column is created, the rolling average don't conflict with different cities. Since there are almost 500 cities in the dataframe. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: split the dataframe on df.city.unique() and run the mean on each city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with groupby methods

```py
df.groupby('city').apply(rolling_mean)
```